# After I install program with wine, I can't launch it due to missing dll's. How do I add them?

Tags: 11.04, wine

I'm trying to install SoftOne's accounting program on ubuntu 11.04, wine 1.2.2, but when I try to launch I get a missing dll error. This is the output from the terminal:

```
niklas@ubuntu:~$ wine 'C:\Program Files\SoftOne\ADMIN6.exe'
fixme:font:WineEngCreateFontInstance Untranslated charset 255
wine: Call from 0x7bc4a440 to unimplemented function iertutil.dll.653, aborting
fixme:ntdll:RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb no mapping for 80000100
wine: Call from 0x7bc4a440 to unimplemented function iertutil.dll.653, aborting
fixme:ntdll:RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb no mapping for 80000100
```

I found the required dll on dll-files.com but I don't know how to get it into the wine installation so that it works as it should... Any help?

Edit:
I've managed learning wine and winetricks a bit better and now I have the following error dialogues when trying to launch the application. What I wonder is if these have anything to do with a missing dependency or parts of the program itself?

```
Can't create object: ADOCommand

An exception occured

Failed to create object.
OLE returned error: H"80004005".
Reason: ...

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getdataset

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getx

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getm

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getoptions

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getcolumns

Exception 24 not trapped;
the class nilobject (object reference: 00000003)
Does not understand: getfont

Execution error : file 'sgmen01qcx'
error code: 240, pc=0, call=1, seg=0
240 Object reference not valid
```

Is there some way I can get someone more experienced to try to tweak the installation?

Comment: Do the people who have answered my question get automatic notifications on that I have edited my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ierutil.dll is an Internet Explorer DLL.  You could use winetricks to install Internet Explorer which will therefore install all runtime DLLs such as ierutil.dll

From a command line type

winetricks

Then select the option "Select the default wineprefix" - click OK

Select the option "Install a Windows DLL or component" - click OK

Select the version of IE you need to install - Click OK.

Note - I'm using wine 1.3 available from the repositories - but hopefully winetricks is similarly available for wine 1.2

Comment: I looked through the system32 folder and found that I already have iertutil.dll. Why do I still get the error if I have that file?

Comment: That version of iertutil.dll is probably released by the Wine team, not microsoft - hence it will be missing some of the vital functions that your application required.

Comment: This actually answers the question in the title so I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'wine' setup installs windows files to the .wine directory In your home. ~/.wine

If you know where the dll should go on a normal windows install you should be able to figure out where it goes in there.

You also may want to check the wine app database for your specific program to see if theres any issues or tips for using it.

http://appdb.winehq.org

Comment: The file existed in system32 and I still get the same error message. When I launch the application I also get the following error popup: "load error: file 'olecl', error code: 173, pc=0, call=1, seg=0, Called program not found in drive/directory". Can this be helpful in any way?

Answer (score 0):

install internet explorer 8 (preferably the one for server 2003) and instead of trying to pass switches on softone use params.cfg in softone's root folder to send the switches. It will work flawlessly.

Also you might need to change the xplorer.cfg and on key UserDefinedFont=0 set it to use one of the fonts existing in your wine installation ie.: UserDefinedFont=Arial:9 so that all fonts appear properly.

In case you 've never used params.cfg, it is a simple ini file format.
[PARAMS]
HOST=nameofserver/ipofserver
PORT=22001 (or the one set in your server, 22001 is the default)

if you've set advanced security settings on, don't forget to add SXCO in the end of the params.cfg file.